# Inner join using JpaRepository without writing the query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have certain entities (which I've linked through Hibernate), that I'd like to query from my database; without having to explicitly write out the query.

**MyParent.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="myparent")
public class MyParent {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "myparent_id_seq", sequenceName = "myparent_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "myparent_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MyChild myChild;

    public void linkChild(MyChild myChild) {
        this.myChild = myChild;
        myChild.setParent(this);
    }

    // rest of code

}
```

**MyChild.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="myChild")
public class MyChild {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mychild_id_seq", sequenceName = "mychild_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mychild_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myparent_id")
    private MyParent myParent;

    // rest of code

}
```

Now, I would like to do:

```
select * from myparent p 
inner join mychild c on p.id = c.myparent_id;

-- basically I want to get all instances of MyParent where MyChild is not null
```

What would return me an instance of `MyParent` that I can then parse myself using my getters and setters. All I've found online are to explicitly write out the query.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jpql:

```
@Query("select mp from MyParent mp where mp.myChild is not null")
```

Or you can use native query

```
@Query(value = "select p.* from myparent p inner join mychild c on p.id = c.myparent_id", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

> findByMyChildIsNotNull()

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), there are more keywords that you may find useful.